# Can I compile office add ins without visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, continuous-integration, office-interop, outlook-addin

Our CI system uses a number of build agents. We don't want to install visual studio on them. Our other .net applications can compile without visual studio. Can we compile office add-ins without Visual Studio?

We will probably also encounter [this problem with registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345290/how-to-build-an-office-add-in-without-registering-it-on-the-build-system).