# How to publish my Outlook AddIn project with MsBuild

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, teamcity, msdeploy

How can I publish my Outlook Addin project from my solution(I don't want to publish all my solution) from command line tools(MSBuild)?

Furthermore I'd like to use TeamCity to publish this OutlookAddin(just this project from solution).

THX.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can find the information you need here;
[How to build an Office Add-In without registering it on the build system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345290/how-to-build-an-office-add-in-without-registering-it-on-the-build-system)

TeamCity supports MSBuild configuration steps, so once you get the MsBuild setup correct, getting TeamCity to build your addin should be straightforward.